# How to include file into assembly and access it?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to include files into assembly, and access it later. in this example, i have 2 themes. one of theme have code like this. this code exactly work. but i need place assets into build output relative to executable.

sakura.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="backColor" Color="Red" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Project.csproj

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="assets/themes/ice_blue.xaml" />
    <Content Include="assets/themes/sakura.xaml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle
        Grid.Row="0" 
        Height="50" Fill="{DynamicResource backColor}" />
    <Button
        Grid.Row="1"
        Content="Change" Click="change_Color" />
</Grid>
```

in this code i load sakura.xaml outside assembly. seems like `Content Include` inside `.csproj` not work or i wrong how to use Content Include relative to assembly output. if output build is output. assembly will load from output/assets/themes/sakura.xaml.

MainWindow.cs

```
private void change_Color(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Application app = Application.Current;
  var resources = app.Resources.MergedDictionaries;
  resources.Clear();
  resources.Add(
    new ResourceDictionary{
      Source = new Uri("assets/themes/sakura.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: what you want is defo possible but Id rather have actual files deployed with the app and read it with `XamlReader`. its a lot more transparent and manageable solution.

Comment: @BoppityBop but how to include and read inside executable? my problem is i need to put that assets relative to executable path. cause style only small. so i think it more approriate to include inside executable.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to use `XamlReader` to load theme from file and `MergedDictionaries` to make the theme available in run-time. Then you  deploy theme files explicitly with the app.

Here is clear cut example: https://www.wpfsharp.com/2012/01/26/how-to-load-a-dictionarystyle-xaml-file-at-run-time/

The key method here:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// This funtion loads a ResourceDictionary from a file at runtime
        /// </summary>
        public void LoadStyleDictionaryFromFile(string inFileName)
        {
            if (File.Exists(inFileName))
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var fs = new FileStream(inFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
                    {
                        // Read in ResourceDictionary File
                        var dic = (ResourceDictionary)XamlReader.Load(fs);
                        // Clear any previous dictionaries loaded
                        Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
                        // Add in newly loaded Resource Dictionary
                        Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dic);
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: okay, thiss how to read. how about to include? is it right set it into .csproj?

Comment: add file. change build action: Content, copy to output: Copy if newer.. use your imagination. its not free consultancy web page.

Comment: i think u already misunderstand. i know how to read a file that relative to executable output build.  my current is work code that read assets from relative path. what i want is include file inside executable, and read it.